# LinkedIn User Resume from API

Tags: php, rest, linkedin-api

Looking for some answers as the LinkedIn API documentation isn't great. If I create a LinkedIn app and a user authorises the app (using oauth) can my code request or otherwise generate a resume as a pdf from the user's details? I know LinkedIn offers a way to generate a resume PDF from your own profile but it is a user application process and not automated.

This will be used to generate a PDF to allow a user to submit his details for a job application.

BTW using PHP REST for the LinkedIn work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so since LinkedIn offers a plugin script called 'Apply with Twitter' I decided to have a bash with it today and it worked a treat! Sends through a user's details and a link to a resume built using the user's details. From there I am able to file_put_contents() to where I want it and with the rest of the data what I please!

Rob.